# How to understand Reactive encoding and decoding

Tags: reactor-netty

Reactor also supports non-blocking inter-process communication with the reactor-netty project. Suited for Microservices Architecture, Reactor Netty offers backpressure-ready network engines for HTTP (including Websockets), TCP, and UDP. **Reactive encoding and decoding are fully supported.**
Quote from [text](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/)
Hi,How to undestand "Reactive encoding and decoding" ?

Could you give me a specific example about reactive encoding ?